# monitoring a process when it starts to run in linux

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, monit

i am trying to figure out how to use monit to get a notification when one of my processes starts to run once again.
let me be clear- at first the process is running, stops to run and then runs again.
i want to be notified when the process starts running again but i cant find a way to do that with monit. (just to be clear if it stops running i dont want to restart it, but if it starts running i want to be notified)
can you help me and tell me how to use monit for my purpose? 
and if monit is not the answer to my problem can you tell me what is?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. when run the command, write its pid to a temp file /var/tmp/pid.application
2. set a cronjob to check the process if the process's pid is changed or not.

Comment: this chance is less, we can ignore. The solution I provided is used by many commercial applications.